# A better practice than spawning, using, and closing multiple python multiprocessing pools?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, threadpool, pool

I have an algorithm of the following form:

```
V = {}
for i in range(N): 
    V[i] = {}
    for j in range(10):
        if should_skip(i,j):
            continue
        V[i][j] = do_something(V)
```

which I have successfully parallelized as follows:

```
V = {}
for i in range(N):
    V[i] = {}
    p = Pool(4) # On each iteration, start a new pool
    results = []
    for j in range(10):
        if should_skip(i,j):
            continue
        results.append(p.apply_async(do_something, (V,)))
    p.close() 
    p.join() # Then close and join the pool after forking the jobs
    for result in results:
        r = result.get() # do_something modified to return 'j' as its second arg
        V[i][r[1]] = r[0]
```

I'm wondering, is this the right way to do this? Isn't it expensive to keep opening and closing pools? Is there a better way to do it that avoids having to make a new pool on each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to call `close` and `join` on the pool, since you're calling `get` on all the individual `AsyncResult` objects, which will [block until the result is ready](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult.get). So, you can just do:

```
V = {}
p = Pool(4)
for i in range(N):
    V[i] = {}
    results = []
    for j in range(10):
        if should_skip(i,j):
            continue
        results.append(p.apply_async(do_something, (V,)))
    for result in results:
        r = result.get() # This will block until `result` is available.
        V[i][r[1]] = r[0]
```